# Django get file url

Tags: django

I want to show the URL, filename and size of the uploaded file on my site.
I tried *object.file.url* but it didn't work.

models.py:

```
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media/",null=True,blank=True, verbose_name="Files", validators=[
        FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf', 'docx', 'doc', 'xlsx', 'xls', 'png','jpg','jpeg'])])
```

And tried this but not working:

in models.py:

```
    @property
    def file_url(self):
        if self.file and hasattr(self.file, 'url'):
            return self.file.url
```

Comment: It's `.path`, not `.url`.

Comment: People should answer this is moments, I'd like to step a side and talk about extension validation, It's NOT enough to guarantee a file type.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give enough information to solve this issue . Where is your `views.py` and `templates/filename.html` file code ?

Since you didn't give enough information so I try to answer your question by using another example.
Suppose your `models.py` file is look like in the below :

models.py

```
class Pic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to="data/media/%Y/%m/%d")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
    def path(self):
        return self.url
```

And also your `views.py` is look like in the below:
views.py

```
def upload_pic(request):
    documents = Pic.objects.all()
    import uuid
    name = uuid.uuid4().hex[:6].upper()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(request.FILES)
            newdoc = Pic(name=name, photo=request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()
            return render(request, 'clinic/list.html', {'documents': documents, 'form': form, 'msg': 'success'})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form
    return render(request, 'clinic/list.html', {'documents': documents, 'form': form})
```

In that case , you can show your uploaded file's url by using `{{ document.photo.url }}` that line of code in your template file . just check out the below example :

```
<!-- List of uploaded documents -->
{% if documents %}
 <ul>
  {% for document in documents %}
  <li><a href="{{ document.photo.url }}">{{ document.photo.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>No documents.</p>
{% endif %}
```